# Cannot hear sounds on Ubuntu 18.04 anymore

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, pavucontrol

The sound on my laptop was working fine till a recent update after which the sound just stopped working. My laptop is a Dell inspiron 15.
I looked up similar questions and ended up installing pavucontrol but when I open it up and go to the Output devices tab and run a Youtube video, the sound levels go up even though I can't hear anything.
[screenshot of pavucontrol when a video is being played](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzyYf.png).
Also I know for sure that my sound card is working as I have linux and Windows dual boot, and the audio works perfectly fine on Windows 10

Comment: Check the "playback" tab and chrome or firefox should show up there. Also, there was a [similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205322/sound-is-available-from-speakers-only-when-headphones-unplugged-is-selected) and they were able to get the sound to play through the speakers by selecting "headphones" as the output device even though no headphones were present.

Answer (score 1):

try  installing **pulseaudio** :   `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`

then run : `pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 210%`

Inform me if that works or not!

Comment: when I did this, I got this error: "Failed to get sink information: No such entity"

Comment: check that issue [Failed to get sink information: No such entity](https://github.com/raphaelyancey/Virtual_FM_Band/issues/6)

Comment: pulseaudio is already running but I still cannot hear anything for some reason